Is this a typo? Is there supposed to be the constant of integration here? I am reading Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang (3rd edition)
in this section of the book I'm reading which is about using matrices to represent linear transformations, there is this section where Strang talks about how a first-order derivative is a linear function. However, in explaining how the integral is the inverse of the derivative and in representing the integral function as a matrix, these integrals don't include the constant of integration: 
then he goes on to say

Is the constant of integration supposed to be included here? I guess I'm a bit confused as to him saying the integral of the zero function is 0 instead of the constant of integration. should I instead see this as something context-specific?
For input basis:
$v_1 = 1$
$v_2 = x$
$x_3 = x^2$
$x_4 = x^3$
When taking the derivative from the input space of V = $\mathbb{R}^4$ to the output space of W = $\mathbb{R^3}$, we have:
$T(v_1) = \frac{d}{dx}1 = 0$
$T(v_2) = \frac{d}{dx}x = 1$
$T(v_3) = \frac{d}{dx}x^2 = 2x$
$T(v_4) = \frac{d}{dx}x^3 = 3x^2$
so our output basis vectors can be seen as:
$w_0 = 0$
$w_1 = 1$
$w_2 = x$
$w_3 = x^2$
where we can exlude 0 as a basis vector?
Thus, since the derivative is going from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, the corresponding coordinates in the output space can be written as:
$T(v_1) = 0 = 0w_1+0w_2+0w_3$
$T(v_2) = 1 = 1w_1+0w_2+0w_3$
$T(v_3) = 2x = 0w_1+2w_2+0w_3$
$T(v_4) = 3x^2 = 0w_1+0w_2+3w_3$
Then, writing the coefficients of T(v) as the associated coordinates in the output space (for each input basis vector) as columns of the matrix, we get:
A = $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$ as our representative matrix for T.
As for the inverse transformation (the integral) $T^-1 = \int_{0}^{x}$, we have:
$T^{-1}(w_0) = C$
$T^{-1}(w_1) = x + C_1$
$T^{-1}(w_2) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C_2$
$T^{-1}(w_3) = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + C_3$
Then, since we are going from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$, we can write:
$T^{-1}(w_1) = 0v_1 + 1v_2 + 0v_3 + 0v_4$
$T^{-1}(w_2) = 0w_1 + 0v_2 + \frac{1}{2}v_3 + 0v_4$
$T^{-1}(w_3) = 0v_1 + 0v_2 + 0v_3 + \frac{1}{3}v_4$
Then, writing the coefficients of $T^{-1}(w)$ as the associated coordinates in the input space (for each output basis vector), we get:
A = $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 &0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\0&0&\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$ as our representative matrix for $T^{-1}$
Actually, I think I understand now. I think he means that if we included 0 as a basis vector $w_0 = 0$, then:
$T^{-1}(w_0) = 0v_1 + 0v_2 + 0v_3 + 0v_4$
Thus, we end up getting the kernel as the corresponding subspace of coordinates and thus there would then exist that 4th column of all 0s which seems to pop up in the $A^{-1}A$? However, now it seems like the 0s applied to the v's are only being applied to the basis instead of the constant of integration?
Edit: I now see, at least I believe, this is not what he meant.

Read lines 2 and 3 of his text again.

It's the integral from $0$ to $x$.  Compute $\int_0^x x \ dx$ and let us know what you get.

Sadly, Strang abuses notation by overusing poor $x$. It should be $\int_0^x f(t)dt$.

@TedShifrin It's not an abuse of notation. the $t$ in $\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is a bound variable (a.k.a. dummy variable) and there is no harm in changing it to any other letter. People often avoid writing $\int_0^xf(x)dx$ for esthetic reasons.,

@user14111 I disagree strongly. And in 40 years of teaching I quickly learned how much this leads students into the weeds of confusion and sloppiness.

@user14111 There is harm in changing a bound variable to a free variable that occurs in that expression: $\int_0^x f(x) dx$ could mean $\int_0^x f(t) dt$ or $\int_0^x f(x) dt$. To someone who understands what's going on, but not necessarily beginners, it is usually clear from context which is meant (usually the first). But that doesn't make it not an abuse of notation.

It is important to distinguish between a definite and indefinite integral. Some people call the latter antiderivatives and the former just integrals to emphasize that they are very different things, even if they are related by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. You only need to include a general constant of integration if you take an antiderivative; in a (definite) integral, the constant term arises from evaluating on the lower bound.
In the text, Strang is specifically talking about integrals from $0$ to $x$. I'd recommend checking each of his calculations -- see whether a general constant of integration appears, and determine for yourself if it is a definite or indefinite integral.

I see. This makes a lot more sense now! Thank you! I had forgotten the delineations between the two!
